# Can snap host CGI application?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

An old python CGI application is running under ocsigen with cgi extension. We just need to configure it as below:

```
<site path="qachina" charset="utf-8">                                           
    <cgi regexp="cgi-bin/([^/]*)" dir="/media/D/www/qachina/cgi-bin/" script="\1" />
    <static dir="/media/D/www/qachina" />
</site>
```

Then the CGI application can run normally under ocsigen.  Now we want to develop our new applications based on Snap but the old CGI application still needs to run for a long time. So how can we configure the snap to run this CGI application.

Any suggestion is appreciated !

Comment: I ever run it using hunchentoot but the hunchentoot-cgi is NOT supported :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snap was designed to allow you to build web apps in Haskell.  We're not terribly interested in serving legacy CGI apps.  I would suggest that you just run it with your existing server and maybe serve it through a reverse proxy.  If you really wanted to serve it through Snap, I'm sure you could do so with a bit of work.  We just don't do it out of the box.